# Error Add Result page breadcrumb

Tags: magento2, error, backend, edit

I have an Edit.php for backend, at first it was running fine and then after i run upgrade, i got this following error:

> 1 exception(s):
>       Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected, supported values: array (
>         0 => true,
>         1 => 1,
>         2 => 'true',
>         3 => '1',
>         4 => false,
>         5 => 0,
>         6 => 'false',
>         7 => '0',
>       )
>
> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Boolean value is expected,
>   supported values: array (
>         0 => true,
>         1 => 1,
>         2 => 'true',
>         3 => '1',
>         4 => false,
>         5 => 0,
>         6 => 'false',
>         7 => '0',
>       )
>
> #0
>   C:\xampp7\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Boolean.php(40):
>   Magento\Framework\Stdlib\BooleanUtils->toBoolean('required')
>
> #1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite.php(61):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Boolean->evaluate(Array)
>
> #2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\ArrayType.php(43):
>   Magento\Framework\Data\Argument\Interpreter\Composite->evaluate(Array)
>
> #31 C:\xampp7\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Lime\Confirmation\Controller\Adminhtml\Bankdestination\Edit.php(53):
>   Lime\Confirmation\Controller\Adminhtml\Bankdestination\Edit\Interceptor->initPage(Object(Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor))

here's my code:

```
<?php


namespace Lime\Confirmation\Controller\Adminhtml\Bankdestination;

class Edit extends \Lime\Confirmation\Controller\Adminhtml\Bankdestination
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $coreRegistry);
    }

    /**
     * Edit action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        // 1. Get ID and create model
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('bank_destination_id');
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Lime\Confirmation\Model\BankDestination');

        // 2. Initial checking
        if ($id) {
            $model->load($id);
            if (!$model->getId()) {
                $this->messageManager->addError(__('This Bank Destination no longer exists.'));
                /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
            }
        }
        $this->_coreRegistry->register('lime_confirmation_bank_destination', $model);

        // 5. Build edit form
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        //the start of error
        $this->initPage($resultPage)->addBreadcrumb(
            $id ? __('Edit Bank Destination') : __('New Bank Destination'),
            $id ? __('Edit Bank Destination') : __('New Bank Destination')
        );

        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Bank Destinations'));
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend($model->getId() ? $model->getTitle() : __('New Bank Destination'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calling the method that not define in class `$this->initPage` either create the Method

replace

```
$this->initPage($resultPage)->addBreadcrumb(
            $id ? __('Edit Bank Destination') : __('New Bank Destination'),
            $id ? __('Edit Bank Destination') : __('New Bank Destination')
        );
```

with

```
$resultPage->addBreadcrumb(
            $id ? __('Edit Bank Destination') : __('New Bank Destination'),
            $id ? __('Edit Bank Destination') : __('New Bank Destination')
        );
```